# Pyqt5 program to open another window

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to create a **Pyqt5 file** to **open another window** with the click of *Push for Window* button and also to open an image when *Process* button is clicked. 
While running the program I am getting these lines as errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled.py", line 52, in <module>
    w = MainWindow()
  File "untitled.py", line 27, in __init__
    layout.addWidget(self.button)
NameError: name 'layout' is not defined
```

**The Program For the same is attached below.**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

import sys


class AnotherWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        global layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QLabel("Another Window")
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton("Push for Window")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.show_new_window)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("Process")
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.show_new_window)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn1)



    def getImage(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file','/home/ucal/Desktop/', "Image files (*.jpg )")
        global imagePath
        imagePath = fname[0]
        global pixmap
        pixmap = QPixmap(imagePath)
        print(imagePath)
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap(pixmap))
        self.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())



    def show_new_window(self, checked):
        self.w = AnotherWindow()
        self.w.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the following errors:

- Using "global X" does not create a global variable, it only indicates that variable X is already a global variable and wants to be reused. In general it is a bad practice and in your case it does not provide any advantage and on the contrary causes confusion.
- In the MainWindow constructor you have not created the "layout" object so you get that error.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
class AnotherWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = QLabel("Another Window")
        layout.addWidget(self.label)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        self.button = QPushButton("Push for Window")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.show_new_window)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("Process")
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.show_new_window)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn1)

    def getImage(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, "Open file", "/home/ucal/Desktop/", "Image files (*.jpg )"
        )
        imagePath = fname[0]
        pixmap = QPixmap(imagePath)
        print(imagePath)
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap(pixmap))
        self.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())

    def show_new_window(self, checked):
        self.w = AnotherWindow()
        self.w.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your support. Means a lot.